# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pegasus'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, google-colaboratory

I would like to try PEGASUS to summarize article. https://github.com/google-research/pegasus

The original repo's README suggests to use Google Cloud Compute Engine, but I use Colaboratory notebook. I'm an English teacher in Japan and I hope my students to try this software easily. They can experience both Machine Learning and English passage summarization.

I followed this instruction. https://github.com/google-research/pegasus/tree/f76b63c2886748f7f5c6c9fb547456d8c6002562#setup

This is my colab notebook.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1p95tZcjhfuCLYh23X3S_gZqRoWVhpIlE?usp=sharing

This is my code in the notebook.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x

!git clone https://github.com/google-research/pegasus

!export PYTHONPATH=/content/pegasus

%pip install -r /content/pegasus/requirements.txt

!mkdir /content/pegasus/ckpt

!gsutil cp -r gs://pegasus_ckpt/ /content/pegasus/ckpt/

!python /content/pegasus/pegasus/bin/train.py --params=aeslc_transformer \
--param_overrides=vocab_filename=ckpt/pegasus_ckpt/c4.unigram.newline.10pct.96000.model \
--train_init_checkpoint=ckpt/pegasus_ckpt/model.ckpt-1500000 \
--model_dir=ckpt/pegasus_ckpt/aeslc
```

Then, I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/pegasus/pegasus/bin/train.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pegasus.data import infeed
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pegasus'
```

This error message says that python can't import 'pegasus' module, but I made python path with `!export PYTHONPATH=/content/pegasus` this command.

Could you give me any advice, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use this

```
!export PYTHONPATH=/content/pegasus
```

Use this instead

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/pegasus'
```

Here's [an example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wImmI1H3vtbq-gDS8EC1DOGzOO4nmSGB?usp=sharing) that can run correctly.

I don't use `/content/pegasus/pegasus`. I use `/content/pegasus` directly, by installing it with `!npx degit ..`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the notebook. They are perfect. I have a question. I copied your notebook and ran. They are completely same, but the out put are different. This is my notebook. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NljLYGio_nIQ2H0crFww9T21Vpyw84bO?usp=sharing  Look at the 8th cell. Anyway, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, thank you for posting this notebook! The final, most important cell does not run for me however, I get `ImportError: This version of TensorFlow Datasets requires TensorFlow version >= 2.1.0; Detected an installation of version 1.15.2. Please upgrade TensorFlow to proceed.
` error. Turns out colab doesn't even allow for defining tensorflow above 2.0.0 . How did you get around this?  Thank you for your help!